# Can an infinite recursive dart generator(yield*) stack overflow?

Tags: dart, recursion, generator, stack-overflow, infinite

I am trying to know if an infinite recursive generator can cause a stack overflow error. I'm not sure if infinite recursion is a correct use case for generators, but I couldn't find any clues about it in the documentation.

Let's take this example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Stream<bool> infiniteStream(bool t) async* {
  yield t;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1));
  yield* infiniteStream(!t);
}

void main() async {
  await for (final value in infiniteStream(true)) {
    print(value);
  }
}
```

Is this a correct use of generators? Or will it cause error/performance problems after a long period of time?
If this is not correct, what is the correct way to implement an infinite stream that can add events to itself in response to received events?

Also I've noticed that without Future.delayed(), dartpad crashes.

Comment: So from what you said, as long as I consume events sent to avoid buffer growth, it will be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can definitely overflow something, but in this case it's likely the heap, so that's unlikely to happen quickly. (It will happen if you let it keep running long enough, though.)

Because the code is asynchronous, the actual stack traces only go from the event loop to the continuation of the asynchronous computation. It doesn't retain the stack which initiated the asynchronous computation (because that stack has already has a stream or future returned to it a long time ago).
It probably has to propagate the yielded value back through a chain of `Stream` listeners linear in the depth of the recursion, but those will be heap-allocated.

That's based on the current implementation strategy. There is nothing preventing an implementation based on separate stacks for asynchronous computations, which could reuse the same stack for the `yield*` operation (or an `await asyncFunction()` call). If such an implementation happens, it's no longer guaranteed that you won't see a stack overflow for code like this.

Similarly, a `sync*` function may lead to stack overflows if you do unbounded recursive `yield*`s, but currently also only uses heap space.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
This is probably a stupid question, but in your sentence "It should probably propagate the ceded value through a chain of linear listeners in the depth of the recursion, but these are heal-allocated", I'm not sure if heal-allocated is a typo mistake for heap-allocated or if it refers to an allocation method that avoids this kind of problem.
What I understand from your answer is that I should avoid this kind of code, and instead I should use an alternative method, a streamController for example, to avoid creating a "chain of linear listeners". Am I correct ?

Comment: Ack, yes, heap allocated! And yes, do avoid code like this unless you know for certain that the recursion depth will be limited. Dart does not have tail recursion, not in normal functions and not in generators, so there will be a linear overhead in doing any kind of recursion. The only real qeustion is what the constant factor is and where that overhead is allocated. 
Fixed the typo now.